# Cobra medical benefits life event

Tags: united-states, employment, new-york-state, medical

My employer has several health ins plans. My employer is required to provide Cobra coverage as it has several dozen employees.

If I were to choose one during open-enrollment, then get laid-off, the layoff, from my understanding, would be consider a life event thereby allowing me to pick a different plan if I choose to continue to use my employers health-plans?

[General QLE question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/116609/qualifiying-life-event-allow-one-to-change-coverage-plan?noredirect=1#comment227212_116609)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you do not get to pick a plan, but rather if laid off you are able to select the COBRA option for the insurance you have signed up for.  Normally this will happen at a substantially higher rate, and it is time limited to 36 months.  Costs are capped at 102% of the employer's current rate.

You did not indicate what state you are in; I believe the requirements differ in some jurisdictions.

Comment: I added information in tags. I also added link to more general question I posed regarding QLE in general. Not certain money or law best place.